# Find $\max k$ in the inequality $y^2 - xy + x + 2y + 5 \geq k\,(\sqrt{3x} + \sqrt{y})$ for $0\le x,y\le 3$.

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> The inequality $$y^2 - xy + x + 2y + 5 \geq k\,(\sqrt{3x} + \sqrt{y})$$ holds for all $x$ and $y$ such that $0\leq x,y\leq 3$. Find maximum $k$.

The answer is $2$. Can someone please solve it? Thanks in advance.

My thoughts on this problem: Since $0\leq x,y\leq 3$, I try to use the fact that $(3-x)(3-y)\geq 0$ and $(3-x)(y-3)\leq 0$.

My second thought was: If this $$y^2 - xy + x + 2y + 5 \geq k\,(\sqrt{3x} + \sqrt{y})$$
is true, then $$x^2 - xy + y + 2x + 5 \geq k\,(\sqrt{3y} + \sqrt{x})$$ is also true, and I sum them together, but couldn't get anywhere from there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Since this inequality must be true for all $0\leq x,y\leq 3$ it must be true also for some specific values. Putting $x=3$ and $y=1$ we get $$8\geq 4k\implies k\leq2$$

so we must only prove $k=2$ works...

**Further hint:** We have $$2\sqrt{3x}+2\sqrt{y}\leq (x+3)+(y+1)$$

**Final hint:** Is it true (for $x,y\in [1,3]$):

$$y+1+{1\over y}\geq x ?$$

Comment: From AM-GM It is obvious thank you.

Comment: From AM-GM $$y+{1\over y}\geq2*\sqrt{(y*(1/y)}=2 $$ Than it follows $$y+1+{1\over y}\geq 3 \geq x $$

Comment: Thank you, can you delete last two comments now, please.